# Filter pandas dataset by minimum count of positive values in column X, aggregated by values in column Y

Tags: python, pandas

The situation: I have the following dataset and want to drop neighbourhoods that have less than 10 phone connections. Each row corresponds to a house in neigbourhood A,B or C. Phone connection is a binary variable, where 1 means the house has a connection.

```
House| Neighbourhood | Phone connection
#1            A                   0
#2            B                   0
#3            B                   1
#4            A                   1
#5            C                   1
#6            C                   0
```

How can aggregate this data on a neighbourhood level, while filtering only the neighbourhoods with more than 10 connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `sum` for new column filled by aggregated values, compare for greater by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) and filer by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df[df.groupby('Neighbourhood')['Phone connection'].transform('sum').gt(10)]
```

**Sample**: with greater like `3`:

```
print (df)
   House Neighbourhood  Phone connection
0     #1             A                 1
1     #2             B                 0
2     #3             B                 1
3     #4             A                 1
4     #5             C                 1
5     #6             C                 0
6     #7             A                 0
7     #8             B                 1
8     #9             B                 1
9    #10             A                 1
10   #11             A                 1
11   #12             B                 0
12   #13             B                 1
13   #14             A                 1
14   #15             C                 1
15   #16             C                 1
```

---

```
df = df[df.groupby('Neighbourhood')['Phone connection'].transform('sum').gt(3)]
print (df)
   House Neighbourhood  Phone connection
0     #1             A                 1
1     #2             B                 0
2     #3             B                 1
3     #4             A                 1
6     #7             A                 0
7     #8             B                 1
8     #9             B                 1
9    #10             A                 1
10   #11             A                 1
11   #12             B                 0
12   #13             B                 1
13   #14             A                 1
```